# MVC Html.DropDownList closes prematurely in IE7

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with jquery. I have a couple of dropdownlists.  When I select one via mouse click and then scroll down over the items using the mouse/cursor, the list closes before a selection can be made, before the mouse can be clicked.  This doesn't happen when I open them and then up/down arrow to select an item.  It doesn't happen all of the time, but a lot.  Just to try something different, I added a jquery "select" control with hardcoded values (options) and it displays the same behavior.  Any ideas?

<%: Html.DropDownList("Accounts", (IEnumerable)ViewData["Accounts"], "-- Select an account --")%>

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you may have another jQuery selector targeting an `input` which a drop down list is an `input` element. That or a hover event that has a selector that isn't specific enough.

Comment: Would a specific hover event help?  If so, what would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Accounts" dropdown have any other jQuery handler set on it?  It sounds like a hover handler (or some similar event) is performing an action on the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, as does the other Helper drop down, but the test select control is all by its lonesome and it displays the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`DropDownList` just gets rendered as a standard HTML `<select>` tag, which I really hope IE7 can handle correctly :) So I suspect some JavaScript fowl play is happening.

Comment: Possibly.. LOTS of javascript being used. jqgrid, etc

Answer (score 0):

Jquery handlers being used, but the select control I added just for testing doesn't have any handlers and it displays the same behaviour.

```
 jQuery(function () {
     jQuery("#Accounts").change(function () {
         var accountID = jQuery("#Accounts > option:selected").attr("value");
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: changeAccountUrl + "/" + accountID,
             data: "{}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (value) {
                 if (value == null || value.length <= 0) {
                     jQuery("#DefaultIndex").val("no default index");
                     document.getElementById("lblResults").innerHTML = "";
                 }
                 else {
                     jQuery("#DefaultIndex").val(value);
                     document.getElementById("lblResults").innerHTML = "";
                 }
             }
         });
         jQuery("#gridShipments").trigger("reloadGrid");
     });
 });

 jQuery(function () {
     jQuery("#Status").change(function () {
         jQuery("#gridShipments").trigger("reloadGrid");
         document.getElementById("lblResults").innerHTML = "";
     });
 });
```